# I read pdf file then for show on the client I use tempStream.WriteByte but it reverse writing

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript, file

By the way my english not perfect sory .

> I use this method . I want to read file then show of pdf format on the client. So this code can do it.
>   But when I show pdf file . İt did reverse write on the document. What is my problem I cant understand

```
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileDirectoryPath + "\\" + pROJEDOKUMANBec.FILENAME);
pROJEDOKUMANBec.SOURCE = ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(fileStream);


public byte[] ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(System.IO.Stream theStream)
    {
        int b1;
        System.IO.MemoryStream tempStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        while ((b1 = theStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            tempStream.WriteByte(((byte)b1));
        }
        return tempStream.ToArray();
    }
```

> And here my ts code.

```
@ViewChild('pdfViewir') pdfViewir: PdfViewer;
    private _openPdf(bec: ProjeDokumanBec): void {

    this._rptSrc = bec.SOURCE;

    this.pdfViewir.Zoom = 1;
    this.pdfViewir.OriginalSize = true;
}
```

> here my html code

```
    <PdfViewer #pdfViewir Id="pdfViewir" [Src]="_rptSrc"></PdfViewer>
```

Comment: `Stream.CopyTo` is a thing, as is `File.ReadAllBytes`. No need to copy individual bytes manually.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is here and not somewhere else? Did you look at `pROJEDOKUMANBec.SOURCE` before converting to pdf?

Comment: You are right I checked now it working true. I think problem in the my ts code